# How do I use udev to run a shell script when a USB device is removed?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

This is my rule:

```
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", 
ACTION=="remove", 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", 
ATTR{idVendor}=="8829", 
ATTR{idProduct}=="0010", 
RUN+="/bin/mkdir /home/zkd/123"
```

It doesn't work. But this rule:

```
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", 
ACTION=="remove", 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", 
RUN+="/bin/mkdir /home/zkd/123"
```

It works!! And this also works:

```
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", 
ACTION=="add", 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", 
ATTR{idVendor}=="8829", 
ATTR{idProduct}=="0010", 
RUN+="/bin/mkdir /home/zkd/123"
```

So how do I use udev to run a shell script when a USB device is removed? I must recognize the USB device with idProduct and idVendor. Thank for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about removed devices is passed in `ENV` rather than in `ATTR` since there's no longer any device to extract information from.

```
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", 
ACTION=="remove", 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", 
ENV{idVendor}=="8829", 
ENV{idProduct}=="0010", 
RUN+="/bin/mkdir /home/zkd/123"
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I wonder that `ENV{idVendor}` is exists or not. But thank you anyway.

Comment: You are right! Use `ID_VENDOR_ID` instead of `idVendor`, and `ID_MODEL_ID` replace the `idProduct`, then it works. Thanks.

Comment: Please be aware! I was following a tutorial which did not mention that udev rules must be on one line! Your lines should be comma-separated on one line, as it will see each line not starting with # (a comment) as a new rule.

This was very bad for me because I was detecting USB removal on my device and calling my lockscreen (physlock).

The result was the eternal calling of my lockscreen at boot (and as I manually bring up my network interfaces, I had no method of remote login.)

I ended up needing to boot from a live iso to delete the .rules file so I could log in!

Comment: @taigrr you split long lines with `ACTION=="remove", \\` backslash